# Django: recursively get (and count) related objects from a "self" `ForeignKey`

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying get all the comments and replies count received by a post, I've only one model for Post, Comment and Reply. Comments are children of posts, and replies are children of Comments. All of this is done using a "self" `ForeignKey`

How to recursively get the children sets ( and count all children) from a parent set in Python?

I have a parent set that contains some child sets as its elements.

My code is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tld import get_fld
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils import timezone


class QuestionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_questions(self):
        stories = self.filter(story_type='story')
        stories = self.filter(Q(title__endswith='?'))
        return stories
    

class JobsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_jobs(self):
        stories = self.filter(story_type='story')
        stories = self.filter(Q(title__icontains='hiring') | Q(title__icontains='hire'))
        return stories
    

class NewestManager(models.Manager):
    def get_newest(self):
        stories = self.filter(story_type='story', created_at__day=str(timezone.now().day))
        return stories


class Story(models.Model):

    STORY_TYPE = (
        ('story', 'Story'),
        ('comment', 'Comment'),
        ('reply', 'Reply')
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    story_type = models.CharField(choices=STORY_TYPE, default='story', max_length=10)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='story', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    ask = QuestionManager()
    jobs = JobsManager()
    new = NewestManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'stories'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} - {self.created_by.username}'
    
    def get_tld(self):
        return get_fld(self.url)
    
    def get_total_comments_count(self):
        pass
    
    def get_root(self):
        root = self
        while root.parent is not None:
            root = root.parent
        return root
```

I'm unsure about how to get my desired result.

Comment: My question is that how can I get total number comments of the post, that number includes number of replies to every comments. I can get comment count by Story.story_set.count(), but this does not include reply count which is related to comments

Comment: How deep does the recursion go?

Comment: Post > Comment > Reply ...

Comment: Do replies have their own children replies, or is it just 2 levels of nesting?

Comment: Two level nesting, I've no intention to complicate it. I just need to find out, how can I get total number of comments that includes replies too

Comment: I've deleted my previous off-topic answer and posted a new one. I could not test it yet (will update it as soon as I can test it) but it should get you on track

Answer (score 0):

You can add the children count to a `Story` queryset items by using the [`annotate(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) method :

```py
stories = Story.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count("story")) 
print(stories[0].comment_count)
```

You can also reference through multiple relationships by joining field names with two underscores (`__`). You should also be able to do

```py
stories = Story.objects.annotate(reply_count=Count("story__story")) 
print(stories[0].reply_count)
```

The [Django documentation about aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) should be really helpful

Comment: This is not working unfortunately, I have found a work around, which is

Comment: Hey, man... annotate is working, but, I just had to filter the story, of which I'm to get the total comment count.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_all_comments_count(self):
    stories = Story.objects.filter(id=self.id).annotate(comment_count=Count("story")) 
    numbers = int(stories[0].comment_count) 
    stories = Story.objects.filter(id=self.id).annotate(reply_count=Count("story__story")) 
    numbers += int(stories[0].reply_count)
    return numbers
```

This is working.

This code defines a function called get_all_comments_count that takes a self parameter, which is a reference to an instance of a class that has an id attribute. The function does the following steps:

It queries the Story model, which is a database table that stores information about stories, and filters the results by the id of the current instance. It then uses the annotate method to add a new field called comment_count to each story object, which is the number of comments that belong to that story. It stores the query result in a variable called stories.
It accesses the first element of the stories variable, which is a story object, and gets its comment_count attribute. It converts this value to an integer and assigns it to a variable called numbers.
It repeats the first step, but this time it uses a different annotation field called reply_count, which is the number of replies that belong to each comment of the story. It overwrites the stories variable with the new query result.
It accesses the first element of the stories variable again, and gets its reply_count attribute. It converts this value to an integer and adds it to the numbers variable.
It returns the value of the numbers variable, which is the total number of comments and replies for the current story instance.
In summary, this function counts how many comments and replies a story has and returns that number.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I've found a work around, which is,

```
def get_all_children(self):
    children = list()
    if self.story_type != 'story':
        children.append(self)
    for _ in self.story_set.all():
        children.extend(_.get_all_children())
    return children
```

Then, using length tag in the template

Comment: This works for smaller databases, but this is sending one SQL request for each `get_all_children()` call. This is not ideal because  each request will take increasingly longer, and the number of calls will also increase, as your database grows bigger. Try to fill your DB with lots of placeholder data, and you should notice the loading time becoming unbearably long